# When should i use range adaptors vs range algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Much of the functionality provided by the various [range adaptors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) seem to be quite similar to the [algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

For example `std::ranges::transform_view`

> A range adaptor that represents view of an underlying sequence after
> applying a transformation function to each element.

and `std::ranges::transform`

> Applies the given function to a range and stores the result in another
> range, beginning at result.

If we wanted to turn a string into uppercase we could use both the algorithm and view:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string in{ "hello\n" };
    std::string out;

    // using transform view
    std::ranges::copy( std::views::transform(in, toupper), std::back_inserter(out) );
    std::cout << out;

    out.clear();
    // using transform algorithm
    std::ranges::transform(in, std::back_inserter(out), ::toupper);
    std::cout << out;

    return 0;
}
```

What do the views accomplish that the algorithms can't, and vice versa? When should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: I prefer `<ranges>`, and in C++23 you don't need to import `<algorithm>`, just `auto out = in | std::views::transform(toupper) | std::ranges::to<std::string>();`

Comment: You don't need to persist the range, e.g. `for (char c : std::views::transform(in, toupper)) std::cout << c;` avoids populating `out`

Answer (score 10):

The short version is:

- Range algorithms are *eager*. They do some operation *right now*.
- Range adaptors are *lazy*. They are setting up work to do at a future point. The laziness means that they compose better.

You use whichever makes the most sense for the problem that you're solving. If you're *just* `transform`-ing a range into another one, the algorithm is the most direct solution for that. If you're building up a more involved set of operations (maybe you're not just transforming every element, but only some?), then you probably want to build an adaptor pipeline.

It also isn't a one-or-another thing - as your example shows, even when you're using the adaptor (`views::transform`) you're still also using an algorithm (`ranges::copy`). Range adaptor pipelines do regularly end in an algorithm. For instance, what if I want the smallest letter (case-insensitive)? I might do that this way:

```cpp
char smallest = std::ranges::min(
    in | std::views::filter([](unsigned char c){ return std::isalpha(c); })
       | std::views::transform([](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); })
    );
```

The adaptors help me (lazily) build up a range of lower case letters, and then the algorithm (eagerly) gives me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, why prefer `meow` or `meow_view`? The *meow* version is more efficient for many algorithms. When necessary *meow* calls *meow_view* to do the actual work. But the work isn't always needed.

Have a look at *take* in the [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.take). In section 2 is a list of times when *take* can shortcut and not invoke *take_view*. One obvious reason is when *take* sees an empty range. While *take_view* may dispatch this quickly, *view* can avoid constructing and destroying the templates necessary for *take_view*.

IMO, reading a pipeline from left to right is more natural than the inside out of nested function calls.

You also avoid typing 5 characters.